# How to run parallel cron job in nodejs

Tags: node.js, cron, child-process

I have some scheduled tasks in my node app. These are scheduled using node-cron. I'd like run job in parallel because I noticed when a cron job is not finished yet that others don't run.
Here an example

```
    let cron = require('node-cron');
cron.schedule('*/2 * * * * *', ()=>
{
    console.log("Every minute", new Date());
});
cron.schedule('*/2 * * * * *', ()=>
{
    let a = 0;
    for(i=0; i< 10000000000; i++)
            a = a + 1;             
    console.log("Hello..... from scheduler");
});
```

How to solve this problem to run job in parallel ?

Thanks

Comment: You could have one cron job and within it you can call multiple functions asynchronously using a queue.

Comment: My goal is to schedule different call to different tasks independently of each other.